# Android starting activity (from library project) in landscape even when specified android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

In my app I have the following sequence of activities:

- Activity1 starts Activity 2 with `startActivityForResult`
- at some point Activity 2 finishes successfully
- in Activity1's in `onActivityResult` Activity2 is started with `startActivityForResult`

All activities are specified in the manifest with `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

The problem is that when the phone is in landscape when Activity2 starts LibActivity it is initially started in landscape and immediately destroyed and created in portrait. In contrast, when Activity1 start Activity2, Activity2 is created in portrait.

The only specific thing about LibActivity is that it is coming from a library project.

Any idea why this is happening and/or how to avoid it?

Here is how the activity is declared in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="com.test.LibActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

The library is simply library project created by me. It is included in gradle like:

`implementation project(path: ':my_lib')`

Comment: mention the library please and how it is declared

Comment: @TouhidulIslam done

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was caused by

```
this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

which I was using when starting the activities in order to avoid transition effects.

Obviously it interferes with the orientation locking to portrait.